# Finding molar mass with MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, for-loop, struct

Alrighty, so I have a pretty 'simple' problem on my hands. I am given two inputs for my function: a string that gives the formula of the equation and a structure that contains the information I need and looks like this:

```
     Name
     Symbol
     AtomicNumber
     AtomicWeight
```

To find the molecular weight, I have to take all of the elements in the formula, find their total mass and add them all together. For example, let's say that I have to find the molecular weight of oxygen. The formula would look like:

```
H2,O
```

The molecular weight will thus be

```
2*(Hydrogen's weight) + (Oxygen's weight), which evaluates to 18.015.
```

There will always be a comma separating the different elements in a formula. What I am having trouble with right now, is taking the number out of the string(the formula). I feel like I'm over-complicating how I am going about extracting it. If there's a number, I know it can be in positions 2 or 3 (depending on the element name). I tried to use isnumeric, I tried to do some really weird, coding stuff (which you'll see below), but I am having difficulties.

test case:

```
 mass5 = molarMass('C,H2,Br,C,H2,Br', table)
     mass5 => 187.862
```

table:

```
Name      Symbol AtomicNumber AtomicWeight
'Carbon'    'C'   6            12.0110000000000
'Hydrogen'  'H'   1             1.00800000000000
'Nitrogen'  'N'   7             14.0070000000000
'Oxygen'    'O'   8             15.9990000000000
'Phosphorus''P'   15            30.9737619980000
'Sulfur'    'S'   16            32.0600000000000
'Chlorine'  'Cl'  17            35.4500000000000
'Bromine'   'Br'  35            79.9040000000000
'Sodium'    'Na'  11            22.9897692800000
'Magnesium' 'Mg'  12            24.3050000000000
```

My code so far is:

```
  function[molar_mass] = molarMass(formula, information)



Names = []; %// Creates a Name array
[~,c] = size(information); %Finds the rows and columns of the table

for i = 1:c %Reads through the columns
    Molecules = getfield(information(:,i), 'Name'); %Finds the numbers in the 'Name' area
        Names = [Names {Molecules}];
end
Symbols = [];
[~, c2] = size(information);
for i = 1:c2 %Reads through the columns
    Symbs = getfield(information(:,i), 'Symbol'); %Finds the numbers in the 'Symbol'
        Symbols = [Symbols {Symbs}];
end

AN = [];
[~, c3] = size(information);
for i = 1:c3 %Reads through the columns
   Atom = getfield(information(:,i), 'AtomicNumber'); %Finds the numbers in the 'AtomicWeight' area
        AN = [AN {Atom}];
end
Wt = [information(:).AtomicWeight];

formula_parts = strsplit(formula, ','); % cell array of strings
total_mass = 0;
multi = [];
atoms = [];
Indices = [];
for ipart = 1:length(formula_parts)
    part = formula_parts{ipart}; % Takes in the string
        isdigit = (part >= '0') & (part <= '9'); % A boolean array
    atom = part(~isdigit); % Select all chars that are not digits
    Indixes = find(strcmp(Symbols, atom));
    Indices = [Indices {Indixes}];
    mole = atom;
    atoms = [atoms {mole}];
    natoms = part(isdigit); % Select all chars that are digits

    % Convert natoms string to numbers, default to 1 if missing

    if length(natoms) == 0
        natoms = '1';
        multi = [multi {natoms}];
    else
        natoms = num2str(natoms);
        multi = [multi {natoms}];
    end
end
multi = char(multi);
multi = str2num(multi); %Creates a number array with my multipliers 


f=56;

Molecule_Wt = Wt{Indices};



   duck = 62;
    total_mass = total_mass + atom_weight * multi;
end
```

Thanks to Bas Swinckels I can now extract the numbers from the formulas, but what I'm struggling with now is how to pull out the weights associated with the symbols. I created my own weight_chart, but strcmp won't work there. Neither will strfind or strmatch. What I want to do is find the formulas in my input, in the chart. Then index it from that index, to the column (so add 1 I believe). How do I find the indices though? I'd prefer to find them in the order the strings appear in my input, since I can then apply my 'multi' array to it.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: `find(strcmp(Symbols, atom))` isn't getting you the row number of the matching table entry?

Comment: Nope. It gives me an empty vector. I've tried that before. I might need to update the atom section. Just not sure how. I tried to run another for loop for it, but that didn't really help. I tried to do a mask where I deleted the numbers out, but it claimed I was indexing out-of-bounds.

Comment: I get a char for class(Symbols{1}). It shouldn't be a table object. I'm just doing structs. Class(Symbols) is a cell.

Comment: Ah, MATLAB structures I use.  You should be able to replace that whole loop with `Symbols = { information(:).Symbol }` I think

Comment: How come? The issue is down more towards where atom is. atom shows up as an empty string for some reason.

Comment: Hold on. I got it to work. The only issue I have now is that it seems to think that O for oxygen, is the number 0. So that's not being included in my new cell of just the symbols.

Comment: That did not help, but I think it's an issue on the writer's end, not mine. I replaced my string's 0 with an O and it made all of the difference. Still annoying. I'm going to strcmp now, cross your fingers!

Comment: It just gave me 4s. How...special. Not quite what I wanted

Comment: Are you doing `strcmp(Symbols, atom)` in a loop, or `strcmp(Symbols, atoms)` outside?  I don't think `strcmp` will search many against many, rather it pairs them up.

Comment: I did it in a loop, and out of a loop. When it was in a loop, I got three 4s. When it was outside of a loop, I got one 4.

Comment: Oh your new loop is no good, because `atom` got overwritten by the first loop.  Try doing `strcmp` inside the first loop, right after `atom=part(~isdigit)`

Comment: I over-complicated this code. There is no way it should be like this. I missed a simpler route somewhere.

Comment: Inside your loop, put `printf(1, 'part: "%s", atom: "%s", found: %d\n', part, atom, find(strcmp(Symbols, atom)))`

Comment: I got it to print them out into a cell :) Now I need to figure out how to use that information to get out the weight, and then pair them up with the subscript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63651/discussion-between-ben-voigt-and-jessica-marie).

Answer (score 1):

Given the string, you can pull out the part that is a digit character with the `isstrprop` function. Then use that to address your string to get just those characters, then cast that as a double with `str2double`.

```
PartialString = 'H12';
Subscript = str2double (PartialString (isstrprop (PartialString, 'digit')));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started, there is still some parts that need to be filled in:

```
formula_parts = strsplit(formula, ','); % cell array of strings
total_mass = 0;

for ipart = 1:length(formula_parts)
    part = formula_parts{ipart}; % string like 'H2'
    isdigit = isstrprop(part, 'digit'); % boolean array
    atom = part(~isdigit); % select all chars that are not digits
    natoms = part(isdigit); % select all chars that are digits

    % convert natoms string to int, default to 1 if missing
    if length(natoms) == 0
        natoms = 1;
    else
        natoms = num2str(natoms);
    end

    % calculate weight
    atom_weight = lookup_weight(atom); % somehow look up value in table
    total_mass = total_mass + atom_weight * natoms;
end
```

See [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4402281/2647279) about how to extract letters or digits from a string.

Comment: I was hoping to try and use functions and stuff I already know.actually learned.